# Old movie about a crazy flying car

Tags: story-identification, movie

About 11 years ago I remember seeing a VHS movie about some kids and their dad who made a crazy flying car. The car helped the man rescue his kids from an evil dungeon. I think the dad worked in a candy factory, too. I was about four or five, so I don't remember much about it, but I recall watching it many times because I loved it. It wasn't a cartoon.

Comment: The title needs spoilers.

Comment: Would "magic" be a better word than "crazy" in the title ?

Comment: @Criggie crazy fits the car better

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Many of those details match the 1968 musical *[Chitty Chitty Bang Bang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chitty_Chitty_Bang_Bang)*. It involves a flying car, the father is an inventor who creates a new type of candy, and the children are captured by the evil Child Catcher and imprisoned.

Comment: Could this be the "dungeon" in question? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-SJAouBCKHo

Comment: I looked it up and yes, that is it

Comment: Fun fact, the original novel that this movie was based on was written by Ian Fleming, the creator of James Bond.

Comment: @RobertColumbia: and the movie produced by 'Cubby' Broccoli, who later produced the Bond films (except the 'rogue' Never Say Never Again and the parody version of Casino Royale)

Comment: Funny how these movies I enjoyed as a child seem so incredibly sloooow now.

Comment: I saw the title of the question and jumped in to give this answer.  Too late!

Comment: Dick van Dyke was actually considered to play James Bond prior to Chitty Chitty Bang Bang, but supposedly did not get the role because he could not do a good enough English accent.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 another Bond connection: Gert Frobe (Baron Bomburst) also played the role of Auric Goldfinger.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there was only one show this *could* have been, just based on the title.

Comment: From the title alone, it could have been either this or one of the Flubber movies.

Comment: In one of the Pippi Longstockings movies, she makes a car fly, but I was pretty sure this was Chitty Chitty Bang Bang.

Comment: Agree with @Robyn: my first thought based on just the title was _The Absent-Minded Professor_ (1961).

Comment: @Robyn - I barely remember the Flubber movies - you're talking about the original _The Absent Minded Professor_ (1961) I hope! - which I saw when it came out but much as I probably enjoyed it at the time I think it would have been improved with an evil dungeon!  BTW, and OT: Growing up with Fred McMurray in Disney-ish movies like _TAMP_ imagine my surprise when I saw him years later in _The Apartment_!  And then after that in _Double Indemnity_!

Comment: @JasonHutchinson Yes, I've seen Mary Poppins!

Comment: I fear the day that someday someone will write a similar query where the answer is "Back to the Future." In fact, this one came dangerously close, if not for the candy factory bit.

Comment: Another Bond connection:  The owner of the junkyard where the children find the car, is played by Desmond Llewelyn -- who portrayed Q in the Bond films starting with From Russia With Love.